# Running Django development server

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create and run a project.

I used the following article:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/?from=olddocs

When I'm running the following command

```
C:\django\mysite>python manage.py runserver
```

This error shows up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 67, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\management\commands\runserver.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.core.management.commands.runserver import BaseRunserverCommand
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 10, in <module>
    from django import http
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\http\__init__.py", line 117, in <module>
    from django.core import signing
ImportError: cannot import name signing
```

Comment: you are using a development version of django? if using 1.3 then you would have to use the appropiate docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: No. Got it from the first option here: https://www.djangoproject.com/download/

Comment: alright from now just use the 1.3 docs, but this shouldnt affect you this early on, i am assuming you used django-admin.py as describved to start the project? anything else you changed yet, or are you just using the default project that was created?

Comment: It's actually has the same instructions from the one I gave. `python manage.py runserver'

Comment: I'm using the default project.

Comment: tell me i fit worked would really interrest me while this fresh installation failed :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I would do.
Try to use [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv).
there might be some old python modules that mess up your django for some reason.
So use virtualenv to create a fresh python.
and install django with pip install.
if it solves the problem its definetely your system python that is messing things up a little bit.

Comment: no problem, its usually the best to use virtuelenv for your projects anyhow, so diffrent projects, that might even be using diffrent versions of moudles dont mess eacho ther up, glad i could help :-)